# Spring Boot MongoDB GroupOperation results null values

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch the count of a list products from mongodb collection using Spring Boot MongoTemplate. In the output the product count values are returning correct but he product against the count is showing null values.

**Here is the code:**

```
    @GetMapping("salesinfo")
    public List<ProductCount> getProductCount(){
        
        GroupOperation groupByProduct = Aggregation.group("product").count().as("productCount");
        
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupByProduct);
        
        AggregationResults<ProductCount> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "sales", ProductCount.class);
        
        return result.getMappedResults();
    }
```

**The output is :**

[
{
"product": null,
"productCount": 2
},
{
"product": null,
"productCount": 2
}
]

Here in the output product name is returning null values

**DB Collection:**

[{
"_id": 1,
"product": "Laptop",
"quantity": 5,
"price": 1200
},
{
"_id": 2,
"product": "Mobile",
"quantity": 3,
"price": 800
},
{
"_id": 3,
"product": "Laptop",
"quantity": 2,
"price": 1300
},
{
"_id": 4,
"product": "Mobile",
"quantity": 4,
"price": 750
}]

I am trying to fetch each product sales info. I am getting the count but the product name is null

Comment: Please anyone provide a solution to get the product name also in the response list. I am really waiting  from the day I posted this.